# configure parallel async event queue on replicated region in Gemfire

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

I'm trying to configure Gemfire/Geode in order to have an async event queue with `parallel=true` on a replicated region. However, I'm getting the following exception at startup:

```
com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.wan.AsyncEventQueueConfigurationException: Parallel Async Event Queue myQueue can not be used with replicated region /myRegion
```

This (i.e. to prevent parallel queues on replicated regions) seems to be a design decision, but I can't understand why it is the case.
I have read all the documentation I've been able to find (primarily http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/reference/book_intro.html and related docs),
and searched any kind of reference to this exception on the internet, but I didn't find any clear explanation on why I can't have an event listener on each member hosting a replicated region.
My conclusion is that I must be missing some fundamental concept about replicated regions and/or parallel queues, but since I can't find the appropriate documentation 
on my own, I'm asking for an explanation and/or pointers to the right resources to read.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Let me put the question into context.
I have an external system sending data to my application using REST services, which are load balanced between nodes in order to maximize performance. Each of the nodes hosts the same regions (let's say 3, named A B and C). The data travels through all those regions (A to B to C) and is processed along the way. This means that region A hosts data that has just been received, region B data that has been partially processed and region C hosts data whose processing is complete.
I am using event listeners to process data and move it from region to region, and in case of the listener for region C, to export it to another external system.
All the listeners must (and I repeat, must) be transactional.
I also need horizontal scalability (i.e. adding nodes on the fly to increase throughput) and the maximum amount of data replication that can be possibily achieved.
Moreover, I want to run all of the nodes with the same gemfire configuration.

I have already tried to use partitioned regions, but they are not fit to my needs for a bunch of reasons that I won't explain here for the sake of brevity (just trust me, it is not currently possible).

So I thought that having all the nodes host the replicated regions could be the way, but I need all of them to be able to process events independently and perform region synchronization afterwards in an active/active scenario. It is my understanding that this requires event queues to be parallel, but it does not seem possible (by design).

So the (updated) question(s) are :
Is this scenario even possible? And if it is, how can I achieve it?
Any explanation and/or documentation, example, resource or anything else is more than welcome.

Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: Before I can answer I have a follow on questions: 1. The way you described things, every member will process every event (not just the events it gets over REST). In other words you are processing each event N times (N=> number of nodes). Is this ok?

Comment: Yes, that would be ok.

Comment: Ok, so why not just use CacheListeners on region C? Creating a thread pool in your listener if necessary?

Answer (score 2):

An [AsyncEventQueue](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/developing/events/implementing_write_behind_event_handler.html) is used to write data that arrives in GemFire to some other data store. You would ideally want to do this only once. Since the content of the replicated region is same on all the members of the system, you only need a Async event listener on one member, hence `parallel=true` is not supported.

For Partitioned regions, if you only had one member that hosts the AsyncQueue, then every single put to a partitioned region will also be routed through that member. This introduces a single point of contention in the system. The solution to this problem was introduction of parallel AsyncQueues, so that events on each member are only queued up locally in that member.

GemFire also supports [CacheListeners](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/events/implementing_cache_event_handlers.html), which are invoked on each member even for replicated regions, however, they are synchronous. You can introduce a thread pool in your CacheListener to get the same functionality.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I've updated the question adding some context.